# Calculating % for value in column based on condition or value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have table below and I wanted to get the % for each type that is >= 10 seconds or more. What is an efficient modular code for that? I would normally just filter for each type and then divid,  but wanted to know if better way to calculate the percentage of each value in type column that is >= 10 seconds or more.

Thanks

```
   Type | Seconds
     A       23
     V       10
     V       10
     A       7
     B       1
     V       10
     B       72
     A       11
     V       19
     V        3



expected output:

    type   %
     A    .67
     V    .80
     B    .50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly more efficient option is to create a boolean mask of [**`Seconds.ge(10)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and use [**`groupby.mean()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) on the mask:

```
df.Seconds.ge(10).groupby(df.Type).mean().reset_index(name='%')

#    Type         %
# 0     A  0.666667
# 1     B  0.500000
# 2     V  0.800000
```

[image: timing comparison]

Given these functions:

```
mask_groupby_mean = lambda df: df.Seconds.ge(10).groupby(df.Type).mean().reset_index(name='%')
groupby_apply = lambda df: df.groupby('Type').Seconds.apply(lambda x: (x.ge(10).sum() / len(x)) * 100).reset_index(name='%')
set_index_mean = lambda df: df.set_index('Type').ge(10).mean(level=0).rename(columns={'Seconds': '%'}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.groupby`:

```py
x = (
    df.groupby("Type")["Seconds"]
    .apply(lambda x: (x.ge(10).sum() / len(x)) * 100)
    .reset_index(name="%")
)

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  Type          %
0    A  66.666667
1    B  50.000000
2    V  80.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Another other option [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) + [`ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html#pandas-series-ge) then [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html#pandas-series-mean) on level=0:

```
new_df = (
    df.set_index('Type')['Seconds'].ge(10).mean(level=0)
        .round(2)
        .reset_index(name='%')
)
```

`new_df`:

```
  Type     %
0    A  0.67
1    V  0.80
2    B  0.50
```